# Good Python Libraries for iPod Synchronization

Tags: python, ipod

I am making a music application, and want to be able to synchronize with the iPod from my application. Has anyone had any experience in doing this with python, and if so what would you recommend?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used it, but [libgpod](http://www.gtkpod.org/libgpod/) does appear to have python bindings.

Answer (score 0):

i made this program to you.
it will Work with more devices

https://sites.google.com/site/yousaywemakeit/programs/musicparser