# API to copy music to iPod

Tags: java, python, ipod

Is there an API to copy music (files on disk) to an iPod?

Any language will do, but preferably Java or python.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1922371/422353

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take a look at [gtkpod](http://www.gtkpod.org/wiki/Home) for Linux/Mac, and the libraries it uses. More specifically the [libgpod](http://www.gtkpod.org/libgpod/docs/) that gtkpod(and other programs) use.

Comment: Sweet. It has Python bindings. Thanks v.much.

Answer (score 5):

I believe the transfer protocol between iTunes and ipod is a closed one..and hence dont think there is a publicly available protocol.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts. I suppose using something like libgpod exposes the risk that Apple will flip out and lock it all down. Bastards.